# JPA metamodel generation failure with Hibernate 6.3

Tags: hibernate, jpamodelgen

I tried to generate JPA Metamodel in Hibernate 6.3 project so I added the jpamodelgen dependency:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <release>20</release>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <annotationProcessorPath>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
                    </annotationProcessorPath>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And then tried to build the project: mvn install

But received an error:
*Error generating JPA metamodel: Range [0, 3) out of bounds for length 1*

I enabled debug mode but it didn't add any valuable information.